# Vertical asymptote of certain function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Define $f(x)$ in the following way $f(x)=\frac{(-1)^{[\frac{1}{x}]}}{x}$ where $[y]$ denotes the integer part of $y$. Then the limit $\lim_{x \to 0^+}f(x)$ does not exist: however the graph of this function splits into two "pieces" one approaching $+\infty$ and the other $-\infty$. Do we say that $f$ has got (say right, for left it is analogous) vertical asymptote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the definition from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptote#Vertical_asymptotes):

The line $x = a$ is a vertical asymptote of the graph of the function $y = ƒ(x)$ if at least one of the following statements is true:

$\lim _{x\to a^{-}}f(x)=\pm \infty\\
\lim _{x\to a^{+}}f(x)=\pm \infty$

Indeed, this is true, so we have a vertical asymptote.

Comment: But here the limit $\lim_{x \to 0^+}f(x)$ does not exist however there is no sequence $x_n \to 0^+$ such that $f(x_n)$ remains bounded.

Comment: @Totentanz I thought about this, and the best response I have is to take limits inferior and superior to separate the cases.